# How do I make a black background behind my 'li' elements?

Tags: html, css

What do I do wrong? As I've understood, this code should make a black background behind the sideMenu-id, but it does not. Why?

CSS:

```
/* The side menu */
.bg_ #sidemenu {
    background-color: black;
    height: 20%;
}

.sideMenu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
}

/* Menu buttons */

.btn_ a {
    color: black;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.hover_btn {
    background-color: #CC4545;
}
```

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/RBTT8/183/

Comment: where is the element with a id of sidemenu??

Comment: You have pasted the whole HTML document in the HTML pane in the fiddle, but it should only be the content of the body tag.

Comment: Well, I have never used JS Fiddle before, so I just copied everything from Sublime Editor to test it. :p

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. Your selector is `.bg_ #sidemenu` but it should be `.bg_ .sideMenu` (you use a period for a class, the # is for an ID. And it's case-sensitive.)
2. Since the list items are floated, the ul element collapses, so to expand it, add overflow:auto;

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RBTT8/184/)**

Comment: But now the buttons are behind the background. Why? Is it something I did wrong? I am thinking maybe the z-index is to blame. :/
(The sideMenu was originally an id, but I changed it to a class)

Comment: They're not behind the background, they're just black too. Change the background to something other than black to see it.